# Reset default axis tics on matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create an arbitrary number of plots in a single column using the same x-axis.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N=1000
x = np.linspace(-.5,1.5,num=N)
xshift = x-0.5
Bz = 30*np.exp(-xshift**8/0.00125)*np.sin(xshift*2.*np.pi)
Np = 30*np.exp(-xshift**10/0.00125)+5
Vx = 200*np.exp(-xshift**10/0.00125)+400

fig = plt.figure()

#list of tuples of the form `(data, label)`    
data_list = [(Bz,"B_z"),(Vx,"V_x"),(Np,"N_p")]

for i,(data,lab) in enumerate(data_list,1):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(len(data_list),1,i)
    ax.set_ylabel("$\mathrm{%s}$"%lab)
    ax.get_xaxis().set_ticklabels([])
    ax.plot(x,data)
else:
    #Reset default tick labels here on ax
    pass

plt.show()
```

For this plot, it would be logical for the last plot to display the xtic labels whereas all the other plots have that information left off.  I *could* pop the last item off the `data_list` and spell it out explicitly, but that seems hacky to me.  Is there an elegant way to tell a matplotlib Axes that it should restore the default `xticlabel` settings?

(some [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, but I think it might be as "hacky" as you fear.  I also think it's probably the Right Way.  :)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N=1000
x = np.linspace(-.5,1.5,num=N)
xshift = x-0.5
Bz = 30*np.exp(-xshift**8/0.00125)*np.sin(xshift*2.*np.pi)
Np = 30*np.exp(-xshift**10/0.00125)+5
Vx = 200*np.exp(-xshift**10/0.00125)+400

fig = plt.figure()

#list of tuples of the form `(data, label)`    
data_list = [(Bz,"B_z"),(Vx,"V_x"),(Np,"N_p")]

left = .15
height = .2
width = .7
bottom = .0
axes_ticks = []
axes = []
for i,(data,lab) in enumerate(data_list,1):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(len(data_list),1,i)
    bottom += height
    ax.set_position((left, bottom, width, height))

    ax.set_ylabel("$\mathrm{%s}$"%lab)
    axes_ticks.append(ax.get_xaxis().get_ticklocs())
    ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
    ax.plot(x,data)
    axes.append(ax)
else:
    #Reset default tick labels here on ax
    axes[0].get_xaxis().set_ticks(axes_ticks[0])


plt.show()
```

Comment: This seems a bit silly to me.  It seems like this *should* be a reasonably easy operation.  As it is, I don't particularly want to hard-code the height and width of each plot to make this work.  That doesn't seem like the *Right Way* to me :).  But thanks, this is better than anything I came up with so far.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, at least you're not using hard-coded rasterized coordinates, it's all relative to the display.